# C# Determining actual print area

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing

In C#, .NET 3.5 with winforms I am working on a print preview control. It seems to work fine, but when I print an A4 page I scanned in at real size on an A3 page, teh scale is out by about  3%...

I am using the following code to compute the actual printable area of the page based on the setting selected by the user and I am wondering if I maybe got those calculations wrong?

```
public static RectangleF GetPrintArea(PageSettings PageSettings)
    {
        float[] margins;
        RectangleF printArea;

        // Get the actual page bounds
        printArea = PageSettings.Bounds;

        // Calculate the hard margins taking into account page orientation
        margins = new float[4];
        // Left
        margins[0] = !PageSettings.Landscape ? PageSettings.HardMarginX : PageSettings.HardMarginY;
        // Top
        margins[1] = !PageSettings.Landscape ? PageSettings.HardMarginY : PageSettings.HardMarginX;
        // Right
        margins[2] = margins[0];
        // Bottom
        margins[3] = margins[1];

        // Calculate the real print margins taking into account teh hard and soft margins
        // left
        margins[0] = Math.Max(margins[0], PageSettings.Margins.Left);
        // Top
        margins[1] = Math.Max(margins[1], PageSettings.Margins.Top);
        // Right
        margins[2] = Math.Max(margins[2], PageSettings.Margins.Right);
        // Bottom
        margins[3] = Math.Max(margins[3], PageSettings.Margins.Bottom);

        return new RectangleF(
            new PointF(margins[0], margins[1]),
            new SizeF(printArea.Width - (margins[0] + margins[2]), printArea.Height - (margins[1] + margins[3]))
         );
    }
```

This should return a rectangle which gives the actual area of the page on printing will happen. I use this rectangle for generating both the preview and the printout.

The code for printing out is as follows:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Draws the image on the printing surface
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Graphics">The graohics object with which to draw</param>
    protected virtual void PrintImage(Graphics Graphics)
    {
        RectangleF imageBoundingBox;
        RectangleF visibleImageBoundingBox;
        RectangleF visibleImage;

        // Offset the visible bounding box location by the position of the print area so as to print right within the margins
        Graphics.TranslateTransform(-this.Page.PrintableArea.Left, -this.Page.PrintableArea.Top);

        // Calculate the bounding box of the scaled image
        imageBoundingBox = new RectangleF(this.Page.PrintAreaOrigin.Add(this.ImagePrintLocation), this.Image.Size.Multiply(this.ImagePrintScale));

        // Calculate the position and size of the portion of the image bounding box visible in the viewport
        visibleImageBoundingBox = RectangleF.Intersect(imageBoundingBox, this.Page.PrintArea);

        // Calculate the portion of the image which corresponds to the visible bounding box
        visibleImage = new RectangleF(
            new PointF(
                imageBoundingBox.X < this.Page.PrintArea.Left ? Math.Min(this.Page.PrintArea.Left - imageBoundingBox.X, imageBoundingBox.Width) : 0,
                imageBoundingBox.Y < this.Page.PrintArea.Top ? Math.Min(this.Page.PrintArea.Top - imageBoundingBox.Y, imageBoundingBox.Height) : 0
            ).Divide(this.ImagePrintScale),
            visibleImageBoundingBox.Size.Divide(this.ImagePrintScale)
        );

        // Draw the image
        Graphics.DrawImage(this.Image, visibleImageBoundingBox, visibleImage, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
```

Where `Page` is a class which contains the page bounds (`PageArea`), the printable area `PrintableArea` and the actual print area (`PrintArea`). The actual print area is the area which is given by the previous rectangle.

Something must be wrong with this approach, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is. If anybody can identify what's wrong I would be very grateful...

Comment: why dont you use printdocument control with the printpage event,the printpageeventargs has all those settings.

Comment: I do use that. That's where the Graphics object comes from. But this is for a graphic preview interface and as far as I know I cannot get the actual page bounds from the `printdocument` without firing an actual print event...

Comment: take a look at this it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761633/how-to-find-the-actual-printable-area-printdocument

Comment: Thanks, that's actually where I am coming from. Turns out that the difference is due to the printer itself... maybe it is not calibrated or I am just expecting too much accuracy from it.