# Printing does not start at the top edge of the page

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing

I am trying to print some `string`s using `Graphicss.DrawString()`. I have set margins to the `printdocument` but does not start from the origin of the page. I have set `margins` to `(0,0,0,0)` but somehow it prints half centimeter below the top edge of the page. Another thing is that it can print from left edge.

Below is my code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ////PaperSize pkCustomSize1 = new PaperSize("First custom size", 1020, 3517);
        ////printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = pkCustomSize1;
        printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
        printDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = this.comboBox1.Text;
        Margins margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        printDocument1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = margins;
        printPreviewDialog1.Show();
        printDocument1.Print();
    }

private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        int resX = GetPrinterResolutionX(comboBox1);
        int resY = PrnOpra.GetPrinterResolutionY(comboBox1);
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;

        float scale = resX / ScrnRes;
        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(367, 1205);
        g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black, 0.5F), panel9.Location.X / 2, panel9.Location.Y / 2, panel9.Width, panel9.Height);
        g.DrawImage(bm, 0, 0);
}
```

What's wrong with code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set the `PrintDocument.OriginAtMargins` property to true to consider your margins.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.originatmargins(v=vs.110).aspx),

`When OriginAtMargins is true, the Graphics object location takes into account the PageSettings.Margins property value and the printable area of the page`

But printing from the exact edge depends on the printable area which is defined by the physical limitations of the printing device. Check the `HardMarginX` and `HardMarginY` to get the physical origin of the printer. For more information refer the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761633/how-to-find-the-actual-printable-area-printdocument) question.

Comment: Suppose I want to print from the left-top corner of the page, what should be the code.? I am asking this because, I set `PrintDocument.OriginMargins` to `true` after assigning `margins`, but prints even lower than before.

Comment: @DhavalR , see my edited answer. Printing from left-top corner should be supported by your printer. To have more clarity see the answer of the question I have linked.

Comment: That means there is no way to print outside the max rectangle. Then what should I do to print stickers (to be used on Invitation cards). The stickers on the sheet are very near to the top edge. And I am using laser printer.

Comment: @DhavalR , unless your printing device supports you can't print at the top edge. You could try setting negative margins with `OriginAtMargins` true. But most probably the print will be clipped.