# Printing Properly in C#

Tags: c#, printing

I really don't get how to adjust the right settings for printing.

Using `OriginAtMargins` makes my margins work, but `Margin(0, 0, 0, 0)` goes outside the paper size *(which is **302x700**)*, and drawing a rectangle using the `PageBounds` sets it in the center, with I estimate to have 1-inch margins, and the `MarginBounds` sets in at the center of the `PageBounds` which also has a 1-inch margins. And most of the time, the preview is very different from the printed one, especially at the margins.

When I'm not using `OriginAtMargins`, the `PageBounds` is the same as the paper size, and the `MarginsBounds` is set at the center with 1-inch margins. The problem here is that although the preview shows the contents nicely, the right side of the document is being cut off when printed, so I had to adjust the rectangle.

Overall, I can hard-code the "just right" sizes of the rectangle/margin, but there will be too much unnecessary estimates and trial-and-error.

**My question is:** What are the proper settings for printing? So that the preview and the printed is in sync, and what you coded is what you see, especially in sizes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the actual printable area? (PrintDocument)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761633/how-to-find-the-actual-printable-area-printdocument). Also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21449328/1132334

Comment: @dlatikay I already both saw that, I learned `OriginAtMargins` in the second link