# Print rectangle in specified position

Tags: c#, printdocument

I would print rectangle in specified position from c# application.
For example 1 centimeter from the left edge of sheet and 1 centimeter from the  top edge of sheet.

I tried something like this:

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
    Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
    e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;
    e.PageSettings.Margins = new Margins(10, 10, 10, 10);        
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 50, 90);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, rect);
}
```

But it does not work correctly.

Comment: _But it does not work correctly._ Is not a helpful description of your problem! - Also: Since the margins are already at 10,10 why not print to 0,0 ??

Comment: My mistake, but although change to new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 90) on print rectangle is in 3 milimeter from the left edge of sheet and 2 milimeter from the top edge of sheet.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761633/how-to-find-the-actual-printable-area-printdocument) seems to be a very helpful discussion of the whole matter.

If you want your margins to work you need to change the `PrintDocument.OriginsAtMargins` from its default (false) to true.

As you don't seem to do that, your origin will be at the **printable area** , which is **printer-dependent** and seems to be at (3,2)mm for your printer. A simple test for this would be to print to a `PDF` printer, which ought to have the full page as its printable area; so it should appear at the top left of its page.

So if you add `printDocument.OriginAtMargins = true;` to maybe the `BeginPrint` event (or whereever you set up th page) and then print the rectangle to (0,0) it should appear at the margins you have set..

Answer (score 0):

I change void to :

```
printDocument1.OriginAtMargins = true;
Graphics g = e.Graphics;
Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;
e.PageSettings.Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 20, 20);
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, rect);
```

Now on print I have rectangle in 13 milimeter from the left edge of sheet and 12 milimeter from the top edge of sheet, but when I change code to :

```
printDocument1.OriginAtMargins = true;
Graphics g = e.Graphics;
Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;
e.PageSettings.Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 20, 20);
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, rect);
```

and print to pdf printer I have rectango on 0,0 on sheet...